# XAML - Simple animation for simple custom control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm working on a Windows Store App with C# and ran into something where I can't imagine it's difficult, but I can't find out how to do it.

On my `MainPage.xaml` I created a user control: A `StackPanel` with horizontal orientation, with just an `Image` and a `TextBlock` inside. Like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<StackPanel Width="300" Height="100" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20" Tapped="LoremIpsum_Tapped">
    <Image Source="/Assets/pic.jpg" Margin="20"/>
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I use it as a custom kind of button to get to some sub-page. Now the thing is, there are **no animations**. I wanted to have the typical animations that `ListItem`s have in a SplitView: shrink when pressed, grow back to normal when either released or when the pointer exits the virtual borders of the control. I couldn't find the animation declaration/definition associated with those ListItems (Common.`StandardStyles.xaml` `Standard130ItemTemplate`). But I found out ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452701.aspx#pointer)) that there are predefined animations for that: `PointerDownThemeAnimation` and `PointerUpThemeAnimation`. But then it took me quite a while to find out how to apply them to the control. You might think the sample mentioned on [this site specifically about those pointer theme animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj649432.aspx) (about C#) should help, but it leads to [sample for HTML/Javascript animations](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/using-the-animation-787f3720/). But I found solutions [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/ab9e46ff-4a49-4edc-bf55-7504ed56350d), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452703.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.pointerdownthemeanimation.aspx).

So I needed `Storyboard`s in the control resources, a name so the control can be targeted and event handlers in the code-behind.

Applied on my XAML it becomes this:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<StackPanel x:Name="LoremIpsum" Width="300" Height="100" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20" Tapped="LoremIpsum_Tapped" PointerPressed="LoremIpsum_AnimDown" PointerReleased="LoremIpsum_AnimUp" PointerExited="LoremIpsum_AnimUp">
    <Image Source="/Assets/pic.jpg" Margin="20"/>
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </TextBlock>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="pointerDownStoryboard">
            <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="LoremIpsum" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="pointerUpStoryboard">
            <PointerUpThemeAnimation TargetName="LoremIpsum" />
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
</StackPanel>
```

Plus the additional event handlers in the code-behind:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
private void Latest_AnimDown(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pointerDownStoryboard.Begin();
}
private void Latest_AnimUp(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pointerUpStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

This worked. But... as I have lots of those kind of user controls, I certainly don't want to add all that for every control. As mentioned before the `Standard130ItemTemplate` didn't help. So I thought about custom controls. I was hoping I could just define a `MyStackPanel` that's nothing but a `StackPanel` + the `StoryBoard`s, and that the targeting to the x:Name would work and maybe I could put the event handlers in the LayoutAwarePage code-behind, so all others inherit from it.

I started looking for how to do that and found this sample of how to create custom controls: [XAML user and custom controls sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-user-and-custom-a8a9505e).

There's the custom control in a Generic.xml:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
xmlns:local="using:UserAndCustomControls">
<Style TargetType="local:BasicCustomControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:BasicCustomControl">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And a code file, but not code-behind:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
namespace UserAndCustomControls
{
    public sealed class BasicCustomControl : Control
    {
        public BasicCustomControl()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(BasicCustomControl);
        }
    }
}
```

But the sample didn't contain anything about animations. So I played around with the example, trying to add the `StoryBoard`s to the Border or to the ControlTemplate, adding event handlers to a self created Generic.xaml.cs code-behind. Nothing worked.

Then I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/89e96adc-f49c-4f99-8d6d-e9d15ea40b98), but wasn't sure about how and why to put an event handler into the `BasicCustomControl` class. I tried it anyway:

In `Generic.xaml`:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
xmlns:local="using:UserAndCustomControls">
<Style TargetType="local:BasicCustomControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:BasicCustomControl">
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Border.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="pointerDownStoryboard">
                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="Border" />
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="pointerUpStoryboard">
                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation TargetName="Border" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </Border.Resources>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And in `BasicCustomControl.cs`:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
protected override void OnPointerPressed(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Storyboard)this.Resources["PointerDownThemeAnimation"]).Begin(this);
}
```

That didn't work. The `Begin()` method doesn't take arguments and without the argument the build succeeded, but I got an System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException when clicking on the control.

Then I found this on SO: [How to add XAML storyboard animation to a full blown WPF Custom Control in an XBAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205751/how-to-add-xaml-storyboard-animation-to-a-full-blown-wpf-custom-control-in-an-xb)

This seems to be an interesting solution, but I don't get it. Here's also some description of VisualState stuff for custom controls, but again I don't know how to apply this to my needs: [Quickstart: control templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465374.aspx)

Now at this point I spent quite some time on this and I'm just thinking that for this **simple thing** - a simple, even pre-defined animation for a custom control -, **there must be a simple solution**. I hope I'm just overlooking something and it's not really that complicated.

To sum up the questions:

1. Where's the animation of the `Standard130ItemTemplate` defined and "attached" to the template?
2. Is there a control that I can "inherit" from that behaves the way I want (just those up/down animations on three events)?
3. Is there a way to create that kind of control, that I can inherit from - with XAML + Code?
4. Is there a way to do this just with XAML? Is this preferable to the former way?
5. Is there a simple example or tutorial on this?
6. Are there any collections of custom controls that I can download and use? I wasn't able to find any.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom style. In this example I bound the Image Source to the content field. So I just had to put my path to my image in that field (ex. "Assets/Image.png"). It would be nice if adding custom animations like this was easier to figure out the first time.

```
    <Style x:Key="ImageButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
                    <Image x:Name="ImageLabel" Source="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    <Rectangle
                            x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                            StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            StrokeDashOffset="1.5"/>
                    <Rectangle
                            x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                            StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            StrokeDashOffset="0.5"/>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ImageLabel" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundCheckedGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```